# Merging two objects using callbacks based on keys with lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I want to merge two objects by creating a new object that contains all keys that occur in either of the original objects, and specifying a function that merges the values of the keys (values should be passed as null / undefined if not present in one of the objects).

Example:

```
let foo = {"x": [1, 2], "y": [10, 11]};
let bar = {"x": [3, 4], "z": [22, 23]};

let merged = mergeByKey(foo, bar, (key, fooValue, barValue) => {
    return (fooValue || []) + (barValue || []);
});

//merged = {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4], "y": [10, 11], "z": [22, 23]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) that has an iteratee  that decides to concatenate arrays with the same keys.

```
var merged = _.mergeWith(foo, bar, (v1, v2) => {
  if(_.isArray(v1)) {
    return v1.concat(v2);
  }
});
```

```js
let foo = {"x": [1, 2], "y": [10, 11]};
let bar = {"x": [3, 4], "z": [22, 23]};

var merged = _.mergeWith(foo, bar, (v1, v2) => {
  if(_.isArray(v1)) {
    return v1.concat(v2);
  }
});

console.log(merged);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using ImmutableJS

```
const { Map } = Immutable

const arrayMerger = (a,b) =>
  Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) ? a.concat(b) : b

let foo = {"x": [1, 2], "y": [10, 11]}
let bar = {"x": [3, 4], "z": [22, 23]}

Map(foo).mergeDeepWith(arrayMerger, Map(bar)).toJS()
// {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4], "y": [10, 11], "z": [22, 23]}
```